# Zappier - Webhook by Zappier GET - URL With space character

Tags: url, get, space, hana, zapier

The context :
- I want to send request to the service layer of a Hana data base
- I use the Webhook from Zappier to sent POST or GET method (I suppose this is the good component ?)
- I use classic GET or Custom Request with the Webhook from Zapier

My problem : 
- it seems that **if the URL contains a space character, it doesn't work properly** :(

```
example  : 
https://<<the_beginning_of_the_url>>/PurchaseOrders?$select=DocEntry,DocNum,CardCode,CardName&$orderby=CardName  => WORK FINE(NO SPACE)

https://<<the_beginning_of_the_url>>/PurchaseOrders(30)?$select=DocEntry,DocNum,CardCode,CardName&$orderby=CardName => WORK FINE(NO SPACE)

https://<<the_beginning_of_the_url>>/PurchaseOrders?$select=DocEntry,DocNum,CardCode,CardName&$orderby=CardName  desc => **DOESN'T WORK** (SPACE BEFORE 'desc')
https://<<the_beginning_of_the_url>>/PurchaseOrders?$select=DocEntry,DocNum,CardCode,CardName&$orderby=CardName%20desc => **DOESN'T WORK** (SPACE BEFORE 'desc')
https://<<the_beginning_of_the_url>>/PurchaseOrders?$select=DocEntry,DocNum,CardCode,CardName&$orderby=CardName+desc => **DOESN'T WORK** (SPACE BEFORE 'desc')
```

All this (except the last with '+') work fine with Postman

I've tried to use Formatter by Zappier and Text/URL Encode method before sending the URL, but it doesn't work

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that Webhook By Zapier encode the URL before to send it.
So the true URL which is send contains '+' even if we submit a space or %20

Is it possible not to encode URL before Webhook send it ?
We really need to send a URL with %20 or space